# Proxy configuration using Reactor Webclient in Java returns 405 Method not allowed

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor-netty

I am trying to make a proxy configuration using reactor webclient but it throws 405 method not allowed whilst when I was trying to make the same configuration using org.apache.http.client.HttpClient it returns 200 status and in Postman also it returns 200 status.

> I am using GET request in all the ways.

```
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create().tcpConfiguration(tcpClient -> {
            tcpClient = tcpClient.option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, this.httpConnectionTimeout * 1000);
            tcpClient = tcpClient.proxy(proxy -> proxy.type(ProxyProvider.Proxy.HTTP)
                        .host("localhost")                  
                        .port(20003)
                        .build());
            return tcpClient;
        });
        ReactorClientHttpConnector connector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient);
        WebClient.builder()
                .clientConnector(connector)
                .build()
                .get()
                .uri("http://YYY:PORT/XXX/XXX/")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .headers(headerConsumer -> {
                    headerConsumer.set(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authToken);
                    headerConsumer.setCacheControl(CacheControl.noCache());
                    headerConsumer.set("X-CSRF-token", "Fetch");
                    headerConsumer.set(HttpHeaders.PROXY_AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + bearerToken);
                })
                .exchange();
```

The error which I got

```
io.netty.handler.proxy.HttpProxyHandler$HttpProxyConnectException: http, none, localhost/127.0.0.1:20003 => YYY:PORT, status: 405 Method Not Allowed
    at io.netty.handler.proxy.HttpProxyHandler.handleResponse(HttpProxyHandler.java:200) ~[netty-handler-proxy-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.proxy.ProxyHandler.channelRead(ProxyHandler.java:258) ~[netty-handler-proxy-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) [netty-transport-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) [netty-transport-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) [netty-transport-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436) [netty-transport-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324) [netty-codec-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296) [netty-codec-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251) [netty-transport-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.proxy.HttpProxyHandler$HttpClientCodecWrapper.channelRead(HttpProxyHandler.java:272) [netty-handler-proxy-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) [netty-transport-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) [netty-transport-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) [netty-transport-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) [netty-transport-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) [netty-transport-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) [netty-transport-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) [netty-transport-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163) [netty-transport-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714) [netty-transport-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650) [netty-transport-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576) [netty-transport-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) [netty-transport-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) [netty-common-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) [netty-common-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) [netty-common-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_251]
```

The respective curl will be like

```
curl  -L -i -x localhost:20003 http://YYY:PORT/XXX/XXX/ -H 'Accept: application/json' -u USERNAME:PASSWORD -H "Proxy-Authorization: Bearer $token"  -H 'X-CSRF-token: Fetch' -H 'cache-control: no-cache'
```

Whilst curl is returning the response with a csrf-token which I am looking for.
The code by using org.apache.http.client.HttpClient which returns 200 status (Successful)

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://YYY:PORT/XXX/XXX/");
        request.setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authToken);
        request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        request.setHeader("X-CSRF-token", "Fetch");
        request.setHeader("Proxy-Authorization", "Bearer " + bearerToken);
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("localhost", 20003, "http");
RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().setProxy(proxy).setConnectTimeout(httpConnectionTimeout * 1000).setConnectionRequestTimeout(httpConnectionTimeout * 1000).setSocketTimeout(httpConnectionTimeout * 1000).build();
       request.setConfig(config);
org.apache.http.client.HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

Comment: Can you tell us which is the proxy and whether it supports CONNECT method?

Comment: I had done a port forwarding to "localhost:20003" which is the proxy here and it supports only HTTP.

Comment: I mean Netty HttpProxyHandler uses only HTTP CONNECT method

Comment: I found this thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29446945/netty-httpproxyhandler-always-sends-a-connect . But then if I want to make a HTTP GET request what should I have to do ? Also will it throw 405 method not allowed error in this case ?

Comment: Can you just verify with another proxy whether the problem is related to the fact that Netty always uses CONNECT?